# How to get text value out of image with text in python using scrapy?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

Also I am placing how data looks in my scrape site:

```
Academic Title   ---------  Clinical Fellow in Surgery
Department ---------  Surgery-Brigham and Women's Hospital
Institution---------  Brigham and Women's Hospital
Address    --------- Brigham and Womens Hospital
           --------- c/o Surgery Education
           ---------  75 Francis St
           ---------  Boston, MA 02115
Phone      --------- 617/732-6861
Email      --------- email as image
```

Here i'm placing code : in last div how to extract email text from the image..as in site email appearing as image, not able to copy or clickable. Please tell me how to extract it in python 2.7.13 in scrapy?

```
<div class="person-line">
  <span>Department</span>
  <div>Surgery-Brigham and Women's Hospital</div>
</div>

<div class="person-line">
  <span>Institution</span>
  <div>Brigham and Women's Hospital</div>
</div>

<div class="person-line">
 <span>Address</span>
 <div>
  Brigham and Womens Hospital<br/>      c/o Surgery Education<br/>      75 Francis St  <br/>      Boston, MA 02115<br/>    
 </div>  
</div>
<div class="person-line">
  <span>Phone</span>
  <div>617/732-6861</div>
</div>

<div class="person-line">
  <span>Email</span>
  <div>
   <img src="/sites/default/files/hms-faculty-emails/BX0UVXkP.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should get src:

```
src = response.css('div.person-line > div > img::attr("src")').extract_first()
```

then you can get text from image by using [pytesseract](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytesseract)

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image,

email = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(src))
print(email)
```

Comment: but here src = "/sites/default/files/hms-faculty-emails/BX0UVXkP.jpg"...i'm getting error as IOError :[Errno 2] : No such file or directory : '/sites/default/files/hms-faculty-emails/BX0UVXkP.jpg'

Comment: @rajeshbojja you should put the adresse exacte of picture like "http://www.example.com/sites/pic.jpg". for that you can use urljoin

Comment: when i followed above given code after giving this email = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(src)) , i'm getting this error => ioerror errno 22 invalid mode ('rb') or filename :

Comment: @parik..yes on windows 10

Comment: @rajeshbojja try  re-installing pywin32

Comment: @parik..i run this command pip install pypiwin32...got Requirement already satisfied: pypiwin32 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages...after this i run command email = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(src))...still getting the same above error..

Comment: @rajeshbojja ask your question in a separated post

Comment: @park..ok ..already asked in this link...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46169963/by-combining-base-url-getting-text-out-of-image-in-python-using-scrapy/46170379#46170379