# by combining base url getting text out of image in python using scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

i tried this code :

```
src1 = "https://hms.harvard.edu/"<br/>
src = response.css('div.person-line > div > 
      img::attr("src")').extract_first()<br/>
src = sites/default/files/hms-faculty-emails/BX0UVXkP.jpg <br/>
import urlparse <br/>
urlparse.urljoin(src1, src)<br/>
https://hms.harvard.edu/sites/default/files/hms-faculty-emails/BX0UVXkP.jpg<br/>
src2 = urlparse.urljoin(src1,src)<br/>
email = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(src2))<br/>
```

i'm getting this error

```
ioerror errno 22 invalid mode ('rb') or filename
```

how to get email text out of text image..can any one help please?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `io.BufferIO` buffer, because you call function `image_to_string` with `http` path. You need write code like this:

```
def get_text(src):
    response = urlopen(src)
    buffer = io.BytesIO(response.read())
    return pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(buffer))
```

Comment: @marni...to get text in src....next code please?...im running this command..print(src)..getting image url...not text which is in image..

Comment: @rajeshbojja what do you mean about `to get text in src`?

Comment: @marni...im placing my code here : src1 = "http://hms.harvard.edu/"<br/> src2 = response.css('div.person-line > div > img::attr("src")').extract_first()<br/>src = urlparse.urljoin(src1, src2)<br/> 
    def get_text(src): <br/>
          response = urlopen(src)<br/>
          buffer = io.BytesIO(response.read())<br/>
          return pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(buffer))..when i give print(src)..im getting this image link as o/p:https://hms.harvard.edu/sites/default/files/hms-faculty-emails/BX0UVXkP.jpg...but i want email text in that link out of text image

Comment: It's different question

Comment: @marni..can we get the text...if yes..please tell me through code..how to get?